# CGImageCreate: invalid image alphaInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, alpha, cgimage

I am getting a weird error that I am not able to pin point which part of the code is causing it.

When running an iOS app that uses the camera image to detect barcodes, I get the following error:

```
2020-12-27 23:58:53.674730+0100 MYAPP[11942:4109474] [Unknown process name] CGImageCreate: invalid image alphaInfo: kCGImageAlphaNone. It should be kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
```

I am not able to figure out where this is fired from. Can someone help, please?

So far I have tried:

1. Adding a symbolic debugger with `NSLog` assuming this was a log output, but the debugger does not catch it.
2. Since the error mentions that the image does not have a proper alphaInfo, I tried adding an alpha to all the places where UIImage is getting modified (it is getting modified for cropping and rotation)

Anything else I should try?

P.S.: The app is a hybrid app using Cordova and this error did not occur previously when compiled with `XCode < 12` and run on `iOS < 14`.

P.P.S.: I am very new to iOS/objective-c. I can provide more logs if required.

Comment: It is not detecting any barcodes. The rest of the application works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you create `CGImage` object, try to give `bitmapInfo` to `CGImage` initializer.

```swift
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
let cgImage = CGImage(
    width: width,
    height: height,
    bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
    bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
    bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow,
    space: colorSpace,
    bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
    provider: provider,
    decode: nil,
    shouldInterpolate: true,
    intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent
)
```